# I am trying to scrape data but it gets data only of 10 pages whereas there are 26 pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
  import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=on&as-pos=1_1_ic_lapto&as-show=on&otracker=start&page=1&q=laptop&sid=6bo%2Fb5g&viewType=list")

c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"col _2-gKeQ"})

page_nr=soup.find_all("a",{"class":"_33m_Yg"})[-1].text
print(page_nr,"number of pages were found")



#all[0].find("div",{"class":"_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"}).text



l=[]
base_url="https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=on&as-pos=1_1_ic_lapto&as-show=on&otracker=start&page=1&q=laptop&sid=6bo%2Fb5g&viewType=list"
for page in range(0,int(page_nr)*10,10):
    print( )
    r=requests.get(base_url+str(page)+".html")
    c=r.content
    #c=r.json()["list"]
    soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")    

    for item in all:
        d ={}
        #price
        d["Price"] = item.find("div",{"class":"_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"}).text
        #Name
        d["Name"] =  item.find("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"}).text

        for li in item.find_all("li",{"class":"_1ZRRx1"}):
            if " EMI" in li.text:
                d["EMI"] = li.text
            else:
                d["EMI"] = None

        for li1 in item.find_all("li",{"class":"_1ZRRx1"}):
            if "Special " in li1.text:
                d["Special Price"] = li1.text
            else:
                d["Special Price"] = None    

        for val in item.find_all("li",{"class":"tVe95H"}):
            if "Display" in val.text:
                d["Display"] = val.text

            elif "Warranty" in val.text:
                d["Warrenty"] = val.text

            elif "RAM" in val.text:
                d["Ram"] = val.text



        l.append(d) 




import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(l)
```

Comment: Would you show us how many divs are in `all` and why you believe the classes you have selected (`_2-gKeQ`, `_33m_Yg`) are appropriate for obtaining the page count?

Comment: I will post full code below you please visit the link in above code then see its HTML you will understand

Comment: If readers need to go to a page on `flipkart.com` in order to understand the problem, then what happens if Flipkart change their HTML tomorrow? That would mean that people would go to `flipkart.com` in two days time and the answers below would not make sense (they would no longer be invalid). Thus, a sensibly small snippet of the HTML needs to go into the question.

Comment: Please also delete your answer below (it is not an answer) and move it into the question. A code formatting tool is provided, please use that. Thanks!

Comment: Look i have done as you tolt now answer the question I have posted the whole code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the page number in the URL is almost in the middle I'd apply a similar change to your code:

```
base_url="https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=on&as-pos=1_1_ic_lapto&as-show=on&otracker=start&page="
end_url ="&q=laptop&sid=6bo%2Fb5g&viewType=list"

for page in range(1, page_nr + 1):
    r=requests.get(base_url+str(page)+end_url+".html")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help i figured it out .Thanks a lot i was really stuck in this problem  and you helped me out

Comment: I am glad it helped, @ShaelanderChauhan! Please mark my answer as the right one and/or up vote it :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work on standard pagination

```
i = 1
items_parsed = set()
loop = True
base_url = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=on&as-pos=1_1_ic_lapto&as-show=on&otracker=start&page={}&q=laptop&sid=6bo%2Fb5g&viewType=list"
while True:
    page = requests.get(base_url.format(i))
    items = requests.get(#yourelements#)
    if not items:
        break
    for item in items:
        #Scrap your item and once you sucessfully done the scrap, return the url of the parsed item into url_parsed (details below code) for example:
        url_parsed = your_stuff(items)
        if url_parsed in items_parsed:
            loop = False
        items_parsed.add(url_parsed)
    if not loop:
        break
    i += 1
```

I formatted your URL where `?page=X with base_url.format(i)` so it can iterate until you have no items found on the page OR sometimes you return on page 1 when you reached max_page + 1.

If above the maximum page you get the items you already parsed on the first page you can declare a set() and put the URL of every items you parsed and then check if you already parsed them.

Note that this is just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to only first 10 pages from initial URL.
You can make a loop from "&page=1" to "&page=26".